# Display myanmar character

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, character-encoding, southeast-asian-languages

Currently, I'm calling social media platform API to retrieve some information. But the returned response contains some "raw encoding code" such as \u1064.
Is there any way for me to convert it into Burmese character in .Net?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Burmese is not part of Microsoft Language Pack.

You can however dowload this: http://mymyanmar.net/Download.php , which will install Myanmar fonts and you will be able to write those characters.

**Fast Test:**

- Add a TextBox
- Selected **MyMyanmar Unicode** Font
- Set `Text` property with "\u1064"

It should work perfectly.

Cheers

Answer (score -2):

Use cultureinfo -> my(Myanmar)
Will change to myanmar calender.